# How to play any type of audio/sound file using C?

Tags: c, linux, audio

Is there any header file or something through which I can play audio files with extensions such as .mp3, .wav, .ogg, .flax and etc and it should work on most of the Linux distro, no windows needed, only for Linux

I am on Debian Linux.

Comment: A header alone commonly doesn't add such features to your program. Seeking recommendations is a reason to close your question. Please use your favorite web search engine and post a question if you have an actual problem using your findings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here i found a good example: http://hzqtc.github.io/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html

In my personal test I only changed this fragment:

```
while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
    ao_play(dev, buffer, done);
```

with this:

```
do {
    err = mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done);
    if (done > 0) ao_play(dev, buffer, done);
} while (err == MPG123_OK);
```

Comment: Thank you so much broo